# Capture GRAYSCALE image with ESP32 Cam

Tags: esp

For one of my projects, I would like to transfer a camera image with the best possible resolution and as many FPS as possible with the ESP32Cam.
For this I successfully used the code from
https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-web-server-camera-home-assistant/

A grayscale image would be enough for further processing, if it allows a higher speed.

Problem is, if I set the format to PIXFORMAT_GRAYSCALE, the ESP only outputs "Camera capture failed".

Are there any other settings to do?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this with my ESP32Cam with no problems.  I would check that you are supplying enough power; I've definitely seen the 'Camera capture failed' when I had power issues.  Also, I would try a more recent tutorial on the ESP32Cam; the latest Expressif ESP32 Arduino libraries have AI Thinker ESP32Cam as a device choice.  I would try the `CameraWebServer` example in the ESP32 library and see if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that 1 year later you shouldn't work on this anymore, but for every one that need the grayscale too, here my solution.

For reference I've found [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-ov2640-camera-settings/) that we can set  : s->set_special_effect(s, 2);
Where 2 is grayscale effect.

0 - No Effect
1 - Negative
2 - Grayscale
3 - Red Tint
4 - Green Tint
5 - Blue Tint
6 - Sepia

```
  // Camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  s->set_special_effect(s, 2); // 0 to 6 (0 - No Effect, 1 - Negative, 2 - Grayscale, 3 - Red Tint, 4 - Green Tint, 5 - Blue Tint, 6 - Sepia)
```